# ReactJS-FullStack-CRUD-App: Axios not working, Error code 400 on console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I first take my time to thank you for reading this. I am desperately in need of your help. I know there are many questions out there that are similar to this and have been answered but I tried my best to follow them all. Nothing worked, so I would like a direct answer to my problem via this post. Refer to this and you will know what I'm talking about: https://youtu.be/FX5HE_gnOTI

I have a couple problems that may be related to one and another. So I followed mostly what the guy in the video did but there is a problem in my work that says otherwise: When I hit the VIEW button, the information submitted doesn't populate. When I hit the DELETE button, it does not delete the item. (I have to manually send a request via Postman Agent and refresh the browser to see it delete.) And when I hit the EDIT button, it would not save and go back the main page when I  hit SAVE. I have spent hours researching and debugging but none of them worked. Your help will be much appreciated and a huge thank you (I deeply mean it), if you managed to help me fix it.

[The console of my application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEfUp.png)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import StudentService from '../services/StudentService';

class UpdateStudentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            emailId: ''
        }
        this.changeFirstName = this.changeFirstName.bind(this);
        this.changeLastName = this.changeLastName.bind(this);
        this.changeEmail = this.changeEmail.bind(this);
        this.updateStudent = this.updateStudent.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        StudentService.getStudentId(this.state.id).then((res) => {
            let student = res.data;
            this.setState
            ({firstName: student.firstName,
                lastName: student.lastName,
                emailId: student.emailId
            });
        });
    }

    updateStudent = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let student = {firstName: this.state.firstName, lastName: this.state.lastName, emailId: this.state.emailId};
        console.log('student => ' + JSON.stringify(student));
        console.log('id => ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.id));

        StudentService.updateStudent(student, this.state.id).then(res => {
            this.props.history.push('/students');
        });
    }
    
    changeFirstName = (event) => {
        this.setState({firstName: event.target.value});
    }

    changeLastName = (event) => {
        this.setState({lastName: event.target.value});
    }

    changeEmail = (event) => {
        this.setState({emailId: event.target.value});
    }

    cancel() {
        this.props.history.push('/students');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br></br>

                   <div className = "container">
                        <div className = "row">
                            <div className = "card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
                                <h3 className="text-center">Update Student</h3>

                                <div className = "card-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> First Name: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.changeFirstName}/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> Last Name: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.changeLastName}/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> Email Id: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="Email Address" name="emailId" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.emailId} onChange={this.changeEmail}/>
                                        </div>

                                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.updateStudent}> Save </button>
                                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)} style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}> Cancel </button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                   </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UpdateStudentComponent
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import StudentService from '../services/StudentService'

class ListStudentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
                students: []
        }
        this.addStudent = this.addStudent.bind(this);
        this.editStudent = this.editStudent.bind(this);
        this.deleteStudent = this.deleteStudent.bind(this);
    }

    deleteStudent(id) {
        StudentService.deleteStudent(id).then(res => {
            this.setState({students: this.state.students.filter(student => student.id !== id)});
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    viewStudent(id){
        this.props.history.push(`/view-student/${id}`);
    }

    editStudent(id){
        this.props.history.push(`/add-student/${id}`);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        StudentService.getStudents().then((res) => {
            this.setState({students: res.data});
        });
    }

    addStudent(){
        this.props.history.push('/add-student/_add');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <h2 className="text-center">Students List</h2>

                 <div className = "row">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addStudent}> Add Student </button>
                 </div>

                 <br></br>

                 <div className = "row">
                        <table className = "table table-striped table-bordered">

                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th> Student First Name</th>
                                    <th> Student Last Name</th>
                                    <th> Student Email Id</th>
                                    <th> Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                {
                                    this.state.students.map(
                                        student => 
                                        <tr key = {student.id}>
                                             <td> {student.firstName} </td>   
                                             <td> {student.lastName}</td>
                                             <td> {student.emailId}</td>
                                             <td>
                                                 <button onClick={ () => this.editStudent(student.id)} className="btn btn-success"> Edit </button>
                                                 <button style={{marginLeft: "10px"}} onClick={ () => this.deleteStudent(student.id)} className="btn btn-danger"> Delete </button>
                                                 <button style={{marginLeft: "10px"}} onClick={ () => this.viewStudent(student.id)} className="btn btn-info"> View </button>
                                             </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                 </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListStudentComponent
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import StudentService from '../services/StudentService'

class ViewStudentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            student: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        StudentService.getStudentById(this.state.id).then(res => {
            this.setState({student: res.data});
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br></br>

                <div className = "card col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <h3 className = "text-center"> View Student Details </h3>
                    <div className = "card-body">

                        <div className = "row">
                            <label> Student First Name: </label>
                            <div> {this.state.student.firstName} </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className = "row">
                            <label> Student Last Name: </label>
                            <div> {this.state.student.lastName} </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className = "row">
                            <label> Student Email ID: </label>
                            <div> {this.state.student.emailId} </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ViewStudentComponent
```

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const STUDENT_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/students";

class StudentService {

    getStudents() {
        return axios.get(STUDENT_API_BASE_URL);
    }

    createStudent(student) {
        return axios.post(STUDENT_API_BASE_URL, student);
    }

    getStudentById(studentId) {
        return axios.get(STUDENT_API_BASE_URL + '/' + studentId);
    }

    updateStudent(student, studentId) {
        return axios.put(STUDENT_API_BASE_URL + '/' + studentId, student);
    }

    deleteStudent(studentId) {
        return axios.delete(STUDENT_API_BASE_URL + '/' + studentId);
    }
}

export default new StudentService()
```

```html
package com.studentroster.springboot.controller;

import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.studentroster.springboot.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.studentroster.springboot.model.Students;
import com.studentroster.springboot.repository.StudentRepository;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository stud_rep;
    
    // GET all students
    @GetMapping("/students")
    public List<Students> getAllStudents() {
        return stud_rep.findAll();
    }
    
    // ADD student
    @PostMapping("/students")
    public Students addStudent(@RequestBody Students student) {
        return stud_rep.save(student);
    }
    
    // Get Student ID
    @GetMapping("/students/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Students> getStudentId(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Students stud = stud_rep.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Student does not exist with the id: " + id));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(stud);
    }
    
    // UPDATE student
    @PutMapping("/students/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Students> updateStudent(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Students studentDetails) {
        Students stud = stud_rep.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Student does not exist with the id: " + id));
        
        stud.setFirstName(studentDetails.getFirstName());
        stud.setLastName(studentDetails.getLastName());
        stud.setEmail(studentDetails.getEmail());

        Students studentUpdated = stud_rep.save(stud);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(studentUpdated);
    }
    
    // DELETE student
    @DeleteMapping("/students/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Boolean>> deleteStudent(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Students stud = stud_rep.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Student does not exist with the id: " + id));
        
        stud_rep.delete(stud);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("Deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

}
```

```html
{
  "name": "react-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import ListStudentComponent from './components/ListStudentComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';
import CreateStudentComponent from './components/CreateStudentComponent';
import UpdateStudentComponent from './components/UpdateStudentComponent';
import ViewStudentComponent from './components/ViewStudentComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Router>
              <HeaderComponent />
                <div className="container">
                    <Switch> 
                          <Route path = "/" exact component = {ListStudentComponent}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/students" component = {ListStudentComponent}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/add-student/:id" component = {CreateStudentComponent}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/view-student/:id" component = {ViewStudentComponent}></Route>
                          <Route path = "/update-student/:id" component = {UpdateStudentComponent}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
              <FooterComponent />
        </Router>
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have posted all the necessary files. Please let me know if you have any further questions and I thank you from the bottom of my heart if you manage to fix my problem.

Comment: If you just call http://localhost:8080/api/v1/students in your browser, did you get a valid output? 

Axios is async, but I don't see that you wait for a returned answer from it. You should use .then or await for axios.

Comment: @DeeFour Thank you for your reply and my sincere apologies for not getting back to you soon. I'm a newbie in ReactJS and the video I was following was like a tutorial guide for me. (Yes, I know the version is outdated, but it's just for an idea.) I would very much appreciate it if you can show me where to add the async function or the .then() method. Thank you.

Comment: here you can see examples for both: https://axios-http.com/docs/example

Comment: Also, I just discovered that when I enter the URL manually onto the browser, it works as expected (except, it keeps making the field of the email ID null, which I don't know why). When I click on the button, however, it does not (instead, goes to the "undefined" URL.)

Comment: Strange I just copy & pasted the URL. But the editor is changing it. If I click it, then the page opens.